# Set Order of Entries

Tags: entries

What is the best way to set a logic order on a channel of entries. I'd like to be able to set the order of each entry (any unset can default to date afterwards).

Would the best way be just a text field and enter a number? Or is there some other structure?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you explicitly want a *Channel* of entries, then you should go with a number field. If, however, you'd use a *Structure* (with 1 level max), you'd be able to drag and drop entries and use that to order 'em.

Comment: Ah ok i see now. But can i change a channel to a structure without loosing everything?

Comment: Good question. I would say you can, but I would conform with the P&T guys before you do it (or backup first)

Comment: @Tim No, you shouldn't lose any data converting a Channel to a Structure. Might be a good idea to back up your database just in case, though.

Comment: Yes, it worked fine...